# Showing a Haskell list of tuples with custom syntax

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, pretty-print

I have a list of tuples `[(1,'a','%',"yes"),(2,'b','[',"no"),(3,'c',']',"ok")]`. 
How can I show this list as output in the form of `[(1,a,%,yes),(2,b,[,no),(3,c,],ok)]`?

Comment: so you have that list of tuples already and you want to output it to intrepreter without the quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the transformation you wish to make is to strip out quote characters? If so, filtering the results of calling `show` on your data will be enough:

```
 > let x = [(1,'a','%',"yes"),(2,'b','[',"no"),(3,'c',']',"ok")]
```

Then apply a filter,

```
 > putStrLn . filter (`notElem` "'\"") . show $ x
 [(1,a,%,yes),(2,b,[,no),(3,c,],ok)]
```

Once you know that `show` turns a data structure into a pretty string, processing that string to make minor modifications is pretty easy.

Comment: I guess filter will be useful.