# Confusing function application and function composition in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, function-composition

The operation

```
(filter (`notElem` "'\"").[(1,'a','%',"yes")])
```

gives an error. How can apply this filter on that list properly?

Comment: You're having enough issues with beginner material in Haskell, that I'd suggest joining the #haskell irc channel for help, rather than asking lots of easy questions on SO.

Comment: Note, for those answering, this is a follow-on from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683210/showing-a-haskell-list-of-tuples-with-custom-syntax

Comment: Id rather read some list tutorials actually.

Comment: "Learn You a Haskell" is a good one: http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: You might benefit from Real World Haskell as well. I did. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030675/haskell-function-composition-and-function-application-idioms-correct-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` operator in Haskell is function composition -- it composes two functions together.

So your code,

```
(`notElem` "'\"") . [(1,'a','%',"yes")]
```

looks like the composition of the `notElem` function and some list. That's just wrong.

Remove the `.`, and make sure to `show` the list first:

```
> filter (`notElem` "'\"") (show [(1,'a','%',"yes")])
"[(1,a,%,yes)]"
```

Comment: Ahh allright. Isn't it possible doing this without using show and assigning the filtered list into a new variable?

Comment: @thetux4 What result is it that you're trying to achieve from the filtering? It's really not clear.

Comment: @Jonathan I actually want to get [(1,a,%,yes)] after filtering but without using show.

Comment: @thetux4: Why *don't* you want to use `show`?  The questions you've been asking are all aimed at very small goals; what's the overarching problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Antal. Well just trying new kind of basic things:)

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of serious problems. First, your syntax is wacky (`.` definitely shouldn't be there). But the bigger problem is that what you're trying to filter is of the type `[(Int,Char,Char,[Char])]` (that is, a list containing a 4-tuple).

And your list has only one element, which is `(1,'a','%',"yes")`. So filtering that is useless anyway. When function you provide for filtering must be of type `a -> Boolean`, where `a` is the type of all the elements of the list.

Seems like you wanted some sort of wonky heterogenous list or something.